# Simple instructions for setting up Seafile in Windows 2008 R2 on AWS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cloud-storage, server-setup

I need to setup a corporate alternative to DropBox.  After a bit of research, Seafile looks like a good bet.

Also, I will need to host my file server in the cloud.  Eventually I will want to by a low-end VPS but for (free) testing, I'm trying to do this in AWS.

The facts so far:

1. I just setup an AWS Win 2008 R2 server this morning and I can remote into it.
2. I have downloaded and setup Seafile Server for Windows.  I followed the instructions [here](https://seacloud.cc/group/3/wiki/seafile-windows-server/).
3. After installing the server, I can connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 from IE on the AWS VM and I can administer SeaFile.

What I can't do from here is connect to my new server from a client PC.

After installing the Seafile Server application, I went and I opened all firewall ports listed in [this help document](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile/wiki/Firewall-settings-for-seafile-server) on the Seafile Wiki.  After opening the ports I still can't connect to my AWS server from my personal PC.

Again, everything appears to be working fine from the VM when I remote into it.  However, I can't get any client to connect to the server.

Have I missed something or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you open the needed ports in your EC2 Security Group?

Comment: @EEAA, probably not.  I'll look into that.  I'm not new to Windows Server, but I am to AWS and Seafile.

Comment: @EEAA Thank you, thank you, thank you!  That was all that I needed to do!  If you write-up your comment as an answer, I'll give you the up-vote and answer mark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to edit your Security Group to pass traffic through to the Seafile port.